# Object output & typeof() the same but == operand not working with findIndex()

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am trying to get my head around what is going here. I am search for a matching id using `.findIndex()` (I am using mongoose). Despite having the exact same output and type, and using `==` I still return false. However, if I convert both using `.toString()` it works. Unfortunately `typeof` does not give me any more information than that both are objects.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

**Code**

```
moduleids = Object.values(user.modules.map(a=>[a.id]));
moduleindex = moduleids.findIndex(function(e) {
    console.log("e: " + e);
    console.log("module._id: " + module._id);
    console.log("typeof module._id: " + typeof(module._id));
    console.log("typeof e: " + typeof(e));
    return(e == module._id);
});
```

Portion of user.modules schema.

```
modules: [ {
    id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Modules' },
    modality: { type: String },
    selected: { type: Boolean, default: false }
} ]
```

The `module` variable is derived from a Modules schema.

**Output**

```
e: 5a4ee5d7e10c0a20dcb630e0
module._id: 5a4ee5d7e10c0a20dcb630e0
typeof module._id: object
typeof e: object
false   // This only works if converted to string return(e.toString() == module._id.toString());.
```

Comment: Two distinct objects never compare `==` in JavaScript, even when they contain the same values.

Comment: values printed in console may not be actual value and it may be result of toString() method of that object.